# I have magento 1.9.4 and running 3 stores and want to add a jv script from duda in the head

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, multistore, head

It says to add this to the head section but I don't know where it is. This is the script. DM_redirect("m.stuffwholesale.com"); I looked at the phtml which I found in the forum but I just am unsure can someone let me know what to do?  I also have to do the same for my other store (m.providencesilverco.com). I apologize for putting this in the wrong spot earlier.
Thanks Ron

Answer (score 0):

You may have 2 approach to do this:

1. Add via XML. You may add in cms page design section, or add it your theme xml file.


       js/test.js
2. Use system configuration to add it.
   Please go to System -> Configuration

On the left hand sidebar go to: General -> Design -> HTML HEAD

Paste your code inside'Miscellaneous Scripts' it will appear in the head.

This section is also useful if you multi-store.

Comment: I have added the script using #2 but the script is not showing in my head section.  This is the picture [link](http://stuffwholesale.com/images.jpg) what am I doing wrong? thank you

Comment: I think it is correct. Can you F12 to see it is correctly loaded without error ? e.g. https problem

Comment: HI I check the script and the added script is not in the head section?

Comment: Did you add in correct scope? e.g. store view level has value to override it.  Or you are using custom theme which will not output this config value in the template?

Comment: I think I understand but here is what I did I first changed the default configuration scope to my domain: then in miscellaneous script I uncheck the default box and pasted the script into the box. Then clicked save. Was this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. If possible switch it to default theme and try, it is to make sure not your theme's problem